# How to click an svg element in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have an svg object, using Selenium webdriver, I need to click as a button and go to previous page. Using xpath I am unable to do so.
Below is the html code for svg but I am unable to fetch the xpath for the same. Any help is highly appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="title-holder">
   <h4>Home Dashboard</h4>
   <div class="time">3:48pm ET</div>
   <button class="update-button" type="button" data-testid="header-update-link" title="Refresh">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path fill="currentColor" d="M20 12l-2.5 3-.18-.22-.71-.84L15 12h2a5.007 5.007 0 0 0-8.49- 
      3.59l-.63-.76A5.9083 5.9083 0 0 1 12 6c3.3137 0 6 2.6863 6 6h2zm-4.51 3.59A5.007 5.007 0 0 1 7 
      12h2l-1.61-1.93v-.01l-.71-.84L6.5 9 4 12h2c0 3.3137 2.6863 6 6 6a5.9083 5.9083 0 0 0 4.12- 
      1.65l-.63-.76z"></path>
    </svg>
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried using Actions class as below. It passes the test but does not execute the click operation.                                                                                                                                                 
    WebElement svgObject = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
        builder.click(svgObject).build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

Xpath:

```
//*[@class='update-button']/*[name()='svg']
```

Try javascript to perform click action

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='update-button']/*[name()='svg']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Comment: It says org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared, you can safely avoid the `<svg>` element and click on the parent `<button>` element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.update-button[data-testid='header-update-link'][title='Refresh']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='update-button' and @data-testid='header-update-link'][@title='Refresh']"))).click();
  ```